# Bash does not stop for second `case` statement

Tags: bash

In the following script if I give `y` once it goes through the whole script. It does not ask for y/n in case of second `case $yn in`. It only ask for y/n once not twice.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "\nFirst Step?"

while true; do
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) echo "going through first"; break;;
        [Nn]* ) exit;;
        * ) read -p "Please answer yes or no: " yn;;
    esac
done

echo -e "\nSecond Step?"

while true; do
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) echo "going through second"; break;;
        [Nn]* ) exit;;
        * ) read -p "Please answer yes or no: " yn;;
    esac
done
```

How to solve this problem.

Comment: When execution comes to the second loop, `yn` is one of Y or y (otherwise the first loop would not have terminated), and the `read` of the second loop is never executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `read` command **above** the case statement in each loop.

```sh
shopt -s nocasematch

printf '\nFirst step\n'

while true; do
    read -p "Please answer yes or no: " yn
    case $yn in
        y* ) echo "going through first"; break;;
        n* ) exit;;
    esac
done


printf '\nSecond step\n'

while true; do
    read -p "Please answer yes or no: " yn
    case $yn in
        y* ) echo "going through second"; break;;
        n* ) exit;;
    esac
done
```

Alternately, use `select`: it handles the looping for you, and sets the variable to a known value

```sh
PS3="Please answer Yes or No: "
select ans in Yes No; do
    case $ans in
        Yes) echo "going through nth"; break ;;
        No) exit
    esac
done
```

Comment: If I give `n` to first `case` , it does not go to the next.

Comment: You said `n` is supposed to `exit`. Naturally you won't get to the second step.

Comment: `select` presents a menu to you: you enter the _number_ of the option you want.

Comment: Yes "You said n is supposed to exit", how can I tell it to continue in case of `n`.

Comment: change `exit` to `break`

Answer (score 1):

In the danger of stating the obvious: `yn` is already set from the first case step, so the second time around there is no need to go to the default case and read the input again.

Just rename the second `yn` to `yn2` or similar.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "\nFirst Step?"

while true; do
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) echo "going through first"; break;;
        [Nn]* ) exit;;
        * ) read -p "Please answer yes or no: " yn;;
    esac
done

echo -e "\nSecond Step?"

while true; do
    case $yn2 in
        [Yy]* ) echo "going through second"; break;;
        [Nn]* ) exit;;
        * ) read -p "Please answer yes or no: " yn2;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: I tested the script , it has the same behavior as above. Can you please confirm that your script works?

Comment: It'd be even better to initialize the variable (to blank, or something similar) before each loop.

Comment: @blueray I've tested it and it works for me.